# Convert to displacement time signal (from accelerometer) using velocity time signal or displacement frequency signal

Tags: fourier-analysis

Firstly, I try to use ifft to convert displacement frequency into displacement time but the ifft fails to give the original sign.The code as below:

```
close all; clear all; clc
t = 0:0.01:1;
x= 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t); 
s = x + 2*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise

plot(t,s)
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('Displacement(m)')

dt = 0.01;   % time interval
y1 = fft(s);            % perform fft
N = length(y1)-1;
dy=y1;
y = dy*2/N; % calculate actual amplitude
%the y need to x2,because it become half
f = (0:N)/(N*dt); % calculate actual frequency
figure, plot(f(1:N/2),y(1:N/2));
xlabel('Frequency(Hz)')
ylabel('Displacement(m)')

[m,n]=size(dy);
for j=1:n;
    for i=1:m;
if dy(i,j)>1;
    dy(i,j)=dy(i,j);
else
    dy(i,j)=0;
end
end
end % set numbers < 1 to zero


IDFT = ifft(dy); % inverse Fourier transform of fixed data
cy2 = real(IDFT);
df=f(2)-f(1);%sample spacing in frequency
total_t=1/df; % %sample spacing in time
T=total_t*(0:N)/N;% build the time axis from zero the the Nyquist frequenc

figure,plot(T(1:N),cy2(1:N)); grid on % plot corrected signal
xlabel('Time (s)','fontsize',20,'fontname','cambria'); % time expressed in seconds
ylabel('Displacement(m)','fontsize',20,'fontname','cambria')
hold on;plot(t,s,'red');
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: What were you expecting and what did you see?